# Retrieve Application Support directory (and others) in C code

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

I need to get the Application Support directory from within C code (so I do not believe I can use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains() and similar). Is there a way to do this besides hardcoding a path (so that it can factor in things such as sandboxing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` is a C function, it uses Foundation calls that involve auto-release pools so you can't call it from pure C code (well, you can, but it will issue pool leakage warnings). So the minimalistic approach is to create a tiny wrapper Obj-C file:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

CFArrayRef appSupport() {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   CFArrayRef a = (CFArrayRef) NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   CFRetain(a);
   [pool release];
   return a;
}
```

Then you can deal with the rest in pure C, for example:

```
CFArrayRef a = appSupport();
if (CFArrayGetCount(a) > 0) { /* let's get the first value */
  CFStringRef s = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(a, 0);
  char path[PATH_MAX];
  CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation(s, path, sizeof(path));
  /* path now has what you want */
}
CFRelease(a);
```

Im not aware of any direct CF API that would give the path.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm now going a bit crazy getting this to compile. I added Foundation.framework (and tried Cocoa.framework as well) to "Link Binary With Libraries", but it's still giving me 20 errors such as:

`Expected identifier or '('` and `Unknown type name 'NSString'`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your Cocoa source files have an *.m or *.mm file name ending.

Comment: Ah, I was using it in the C file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is compatible to C. So you can simply wrap your call to `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` within a simple C function and have 
that return a const char* to access it from within your other (non Cocoa compatible) 
C code. You will have to link against the corresponding OSX libs, though.